# разница между pattern listener и pattern Observer

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

Объясните пожалуйста разницу между двумя паттернами listener и Observer. Являются ли они идентичными или есть хоть какое-то между ними отличие?

Comment: дубликат вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358622/observer-design-pattern-vs-listeners

Comment: @ValentineAnzhurov как это может быть дубликатом en SO вопроса? =/

Answer (score -1):

Есть объект Observable. Он  генерирует какие-то события. Иначе говоря в него разработчик прокидывает какие-либо данные. 
На примере rxjs:

```
const observable = new Observable();
```

Или

```
const subject = new Subject();
```

По своей сути это почти одно и то же. `Subject` просто расширяет функционал `Observable` (как кнопочный и сенсорный телефон, иногда лучше только один из них).
В `Observable`, например нельзя явно пробросить значение из другой части кода. Об этом ниже. `Observable`- это объект, который ТОЧНО ТАК ЖЕ может отдать нам те данные.

У объекта subject есть метод, в параметры которого ты кидаешь те самые данные.

```
subject.next('строка или вообще любые данные');
```

При чем тут Observer? Продолжу цепочку событий.

Теперь мы их хотим получить. Чтобы это сделать и получить ОДНИ И ТЕ ЖЕ данные одновременно и АССИНХРОННО с чата, меню, всплывающего меню,  шапки и тд и тп... мы подписываемся на события о новых данных. То есть создаем `listener\Observer`- слушателя.

```
const observer = subject
                   .subscribe(data => { ...работа с полученными данными 'data' });
```

Переменную `observer` создавать не обязательно, создал ради примера. Некоторые библиотеки позволяют делать много магии с ней.

Обобщим. `Observable/Subject/наблюдаемый` источники событий для `observer/слушатель/наблюдатель`.
Объяснил своими словами. Надеюсь вышло понятно.